# Showing that V is equal to the direct sum of Im P and Im Q

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $P, Q$ be linear mappings of $V$ into itself. Assume that they satisfy the following conditions:

(a) $P + Q = I$,
(b) $PQ = QP = O$,
(c) $P^2 = P, Q^2 = Q$.

Show that $V$ is equal to the direct sum of $Im (P) $ and $Im (Q)$

I understand that I need to show that for every $v \in Im(P) \oplus Im(Q)$ there exists a unique pair $(u,w)$ such that $u \in Im (P) $, $w \in Im (Q) $, and $v = u + w$. I just do not know how to apply that to these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Correction: you need to show that for every $v$ in $V$ there exists....

Existence: take $u=P(v)$, $w=Q(v)$.

Uniqueness is equivalent to proving that $im(P)\cap im(Q)=\{0\}$.  So, if $v\in im(P)\cap im(Q)$ then $v=P(x)=Q(y)$ and
$$v=P(v)+Q(v)=PQ(y)+QP(x)=0\ .$$

This argument needs to be written up carefully with detailed reasons, I will leave that to you.